# Problems with PHP extensions

Tags: php

I'm setting up an EE site for a client who does not want to change hosts, and the server is giving me fits.

A bit of background: I installed EE before realizing the server was running PHP 5.6 by default. However, it's a cPanel server and the "MultiPHP Manager" allows me to select other versions of PHP. I can run fine on PHP 7.0, but anything higher than that (i.e., every current version) causes problems.

Starting with PHP 7.1, EE keeps telling me "Class 'PDO' not found," which I confirmed outside of EE:

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

However, phpinfo shows the following:

```
--enable-pdo=shared' '
--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '
--with-pdo-mysql=shared,mysqlnd' '
--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '
--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '
```

I'm not sufficiently experienced with server admin to know what this is telling me, but the host says PDO is "built in" and should be working.

I ran into a similar issue with the fileinfo extension -- get_loaded_extensions() shows that it's not loaded, phpinfo() shows it's enabled, and the host says it's built-in.

Is there any way to address this in EE's configuration settings, .htaccess, php.ini, or anything else I might have access to?

Comment: Your `phpinfo` output just shows how PHP was compiled. That doesn't mean the extension is enabled. See https://www.php.net/manual/pdo.installation.php